Binding Factory and model with custom namespace in Laravel 11.x
I have a User model in modules/Users/Models directory and UserFactory in the default database/factories directory.
I made this provider to avoid Class "Database\Factories\Modules\Users\Models\UserFactory" not found error when php artisan db:seed
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class FactoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    public function boot(): void
    {
        Factory::guessFactoryNamesUsing(function (string $model_name) {
            $namespace = 'Database\\Factories\\';
            $model_name = Str::afterLast($model_name, '\\');
            return $namespace . $model_name . 'Factory';
        });
    }
}

Seeder calls this:
$users = User::factory()->count(10)->make();
But now I get Class "App\User" not found error.
Please, tell me how to solve this?

Same if you set $namespace = '\\Database\\Factories\\';? Also, everything done with namespaces should be followed with composer du and/or php artisan optimize:clear.

Without changes

When you call the factory in your seeder, make sure to use the full namespace of the User model. It looks like you're calling User::factory() directly, which Laravel is trying to resolve based on the default App namesapce. Instead, you should reference the full namespace in your seeder file:
use Modules\Users\Models\User;


I already have it.
Even if i call it like this:
\Modules\Users\Models\User::factory()->count(10)->make()
The result will remain the same.

Can you alos doublecheck the namespace declaration in yur Users model.
namespace Modules\Users\Models;

Yes, there is namespace Modules\Users\Models;

use App\Models\User; // or the correct namespace
// Inside your seeder class
$users = User::factory()->count(10)->make();

Clear cache
php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear


Yes, I did
php artisan clear-compiled &&
composer dump-autoload &&
php artisan optimize

Found a solution.
Need to specify model in the factory:
protected $model = \Modules\Users\Models\User::class; in the UserFactory
